# Stop Hbase update operation if it have same value

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

I have a table in Hbase named 'xyz' . When I do an update operation on this table , it updates a table even though it is same record .

How can I control second record to not be added.

Eg:

```
create 'ns:xyz',{NAME=>'cf1',VERSIONS => 5}

put 'ns:xyz','1','cf1:name','NewYork'

put 'ns:xyz','1','cf1:name','NewYork'
```

Above put statements are giving 2 records with different timestamp if I check all versions. I am expecting that it should not add 2nd record because it have same value

Answer (score 0):

HBase isn't going to look through the entire row and work out if it's the same as the data you're adding. That would be an expensive operation, and HBase prides itself on its fast insert speeds.

If you're really eager to do this (and I'd ask if you really want to do this), you should perform a GET first to see if the data is already present in the table.

You could also write a Coprocessor to do this every time you PUT data, but again the performance would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ben Watson, HBase is best known for it's performance in write since it doesn't need to check for the existence of a  value as multiple versions will be maintained by default.

One hack what you can do is, you can use custom versioning. As show in the below screenshot, you have two versions already for a row key. Now if you are going to insert the same record with the same timestamp. HBase would be overwriting the same record with just the value.

[image]

NOTE: It is left to your application to get the same timestamp for a particular value.